# Change the background color of a menu (inflater)

Tags: android, menu, android-menu, android-inflate

How can I change the background color of a menu (inflater)?

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.hostList) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.host_menu, menu);
        }
    }
```

and the menu is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:title="@string/test1">
        </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:title="@string/test2">
    </item>
</menu>
```

I tried a lot of things, but I can just change the colors of texts (or background of text) using "TextAppearanceSpan".. but I need to change all the menu' background.